# C# Jpegの件名とコメントを編集して、エクスプローラで確認できるように書き換えたい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

Jpeg画像のexifタグの中の情報を書き換え、エクスプローラできちんと
表示させるコードを書きたいと思っています。

http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/graphics/getexifinfo.html

上記サイト様を見て、何とかタイトルは書き換えることに成功したのですが、
件名とコメントの二つがどうしてもできません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

調べてみたところ、idの値が、40092がコメント、40095が件名だというところまでは
突き止めたのですが、TypeやValueの内容が解りません。

エクスプローラで表示させるには、TypeやValueにはどのようなデータを
渡せばよいですか？そのほかにも、何かやらなければならないことが
あるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"exif 40092" で検索してみたところ、Exiv2 というC++向けのライブラリの情報が見つかりました。

http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html

それによると、 40092 の "Exif.Image.XPComment" と 40095 の "Exif.Image.XPSubject" はどちらも Byte 型で、値はUCS2でエンコードされている、と書かれています。

もしくは実際にエクスプローラで書き換えてみてから、C#で情報を調べてみてもいいですね。

Byte型に相当する `PropertyInfo.Type` の値はdobon.netに書かれている通り `1`、UCS-2(UTF-16) への変換には `Encoding.Unicode` が使えます。

以下のコードで既に設定されている「件名」を書き換えることができました。

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(@"r:\in.jpg"))
{
    var pi = bmp.GetPropertyItem(40095);
    pi.Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("これはテストです");
    bmp.SetPropertyItem(pi);
    bmp.Save(@"r:\out.jpg");
}
```

---

タイトルはASCIIなのに、何故件名やコメントはUCS-2なのか、という補足です。

EXIF は TIFF という30年も前に策定された別の規格が元になっています。タグの格納方法や型、そしてタイトル（ImageDescription）をはじめとする基本的なタグ項目は TIFF と同じものが使われています。この頃 Unicode はまだ形になっていませんでしたから、 UCS-2 なんて選択肢もないわけです。

一方で、 XPSubject や XPComment などの「XP～」というタグは WindowsXP が独自に使い始めたタグのようです。そのため現在の Exif 2.3 の規格書にもこれらのタグは載っていません。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。
UTF-16だったとは解りませんでした。
タイトルがASCIIだったので、その他もASCIIで入れようとしていたのが
間違いだったみたいです。
何とか変更できるようになりました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

WPFであれば`BitmapFrame`と[`BitmapMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)クラスを用いて比較的容易に画像のメタデータが編集可能です。プロジェクトの参照に「System.Xaml」「WindowsBase」「PresentationCore」「PresentationFramework」を追加して以下のように実行してください。

```
// using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

// 入出力するファイルを開く
using (var fs = new FileStream(originalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    // ファイルを読み込み、BitmapFrameを作成する
    var f = BitmapFrame.Create(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);

    // メタデータを編集するためのインスタンスを作成する
    var meta = f.CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter();

    // TODO:ここでメタデータを編集します。
    meta.Title += "タイトル";
    meta.Subject += "件名";
    meta.Comment += "コメント";

    // メタデータの変更を元のファイルに書き込む
    meta.TrySave();
}
```

また同時に画像のトランスコードを行う場合は`BitmapEncoder`を使用します。

```
// メタデータの作成
// BitmapFrame f;
var meta = f.Metadata.Clone() as BitmapMetadata ?? new BitmapMetadata("jpg");
meta.Title += "タイトル";
meta.Subject += "件名";
meta.Comment += "コメント";

// JPEGファイルの出力
var enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(f, f.Thumbnail, meta, f.ColorContexts));

using (var fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    enc.Save(fs);
}
```

なお上記のコードでも利用していますが、読み取り専用のメタデータは`BitmapFrame.Metadata`プロパティで参照できます。読み込みと書き込みにタイムラグがある場合はこちらを利用したほうが良いかと思います。

```
var meta = (BitmapMetadata)f.Metadata;
```

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。
拝見しましたが、少しコードが複雑で、理解できずにいます。すみません。
それに、WPFではなく、WindowsFormを使用しています。
WindowsFormでの解決策はありますでしょうか。

Comment: @たたぱた 基本的には一番上のコードの`originalPath`と`meta`使用箇所を変更すれば流用できるのではないかと思います。またWindows Formでの標準EXIF実装は質問文で触れられているAPIしかありません。Windows FormアプリでWPFライブラリを参照するのはMicrosoftが公式に認めている使用形態なので、あまりこだわらずに使ってみてください。

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista以降のエクスプローラーでは表示だけでなくプロパティダイアログでの編集もサポートしています。そしてそのインターフェースは公開されています。ですので、**JPEGのEXIFを編集したい**ではなく**エクスプローラーに表示される項目を編集したい**という目的でしたら直接こちらのインターフェースを操作することをお勧めします。
目的の項目を直接編集できるだけでなく、エクスプローラーがサポートしているファイル形式について同じ方法で扱えます。

コードとしてはこのような呼び出し方になります。

```
static void SetSubjectAndComment(string fullpath, string subject, string comment) {
    IPropertyStore prop;
    SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(fullpath, IntPtr.Zero, GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS.READWRITE, typeof(IPropertyStore).GUID, out prop);

    var keySubject = PROPERTYKEY.FromName("System.Subject");
    var valSubject = new PROPVARIANT(subject);
    prop.SetValue(ref keySubject, ref valSubject);
    PropVariantClear(ref valSubject);

    var keyComment = PROPERTYKEY.FromName("System.Comment");
    var valComment = new PROPVARIANT(comment);
    prop.SetValue(ref keyComment, ref valComment);
    PropVariantClear(ref valComment);

    prop.Commit();
}
```

これを実行するのに必要な定義は以下になります。（文字列型に必要な分の定義しかしていません。）

```
[Flags]
enum GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS {
    READWRITE = 0x00000002,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct PROPERTYKEY {
    public Guid fmtid;
    public int pid;

    public static PROPERTYKEY FromName(string name) {
        PROPERTYKEY key;
        PSGetPropertyKeyFromName(name, out key);
        return key;
    }
}

enum VARTYPE : ushort {
    VT_LPWSTR = 31,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct PROPVARIANT {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public VARTYPE vt;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IntPtr bstrVal;

    public PROPVARIANT(string val) {
        vt = VARTYPE.VT_LPWSTR;
        bstrVal = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(val);
    }
}

[ComImport, Guid("886d8eeb-8cf2-4446-8d02-cdba1dbdcf99"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IPropertyStore {
    void GetCount(out int cProps);
    void GetAt(int iProp, out PROPERTYKEY pkey);
    void GetValue([In] ref PROPERTYKEY key, out PROPVARIANT pv);
    void SetValue([In] ref PROPERTYKEY key, [In] ref PROPVARIANT propvar);
    void Commit();
}

[DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
static extern void SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(string pszPath, IntPtr pbc, GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS flags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, out IPropertyStore ppv);
[DllImport("Propsys.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
static extern void PSGetPropertyKeyFromName(string pszString, out PROPERTYKEY pkey);
[DllImport("ole32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
static extern void PropVariantClear(ref PROPVARIANT pvar);
```

質問ではコメントと件名を設定したいということでしたが、設定できるプロパティは[Windows Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd561977(v=vs.85).aspx)にリストされていて、コード例にもあるようにコメント＝`System.Comment`、件名＝`System.Subject`のようになっています。

Comment: いつも回答、ありがとうございます。
エクスプローラーからやるのは解ってはいるのですが、
やはりどうしてもたくさんのデータを一つ一つやるわけにはいかないので、
コードで行うしかありませんでした。

しかし、mp3のタグ編集もかなり手間取りましたが、jpegでも
これだけのコードを実装しないと行うことができないのでしょうか。

Comment: @たたぱた jpegのためだけにと考えると大げさなコードですが、jpegやmp3といった個々のファイル形式に依存せず共通して編集できることが利点です。例えば`System.Music.Artist`でアーティストの項目が編集できます。
大げさでもそれだけの価値があると思い回答しました。